# Adding the integers in an array using CLI Parser

Tags: java

*Homework

In the program I'm supposed to take the command line argument and add the integers.

Example:

> java *class* -add 10 2 4
>
> 16

I have this following code, but for the top example it only outputs 0. What am I doing wrong?

```
    private static void add(String[] args) {
    int[] add = new int[args.length];
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < add.length; i++) {
        sum += add[i];
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's examine your code!

```java
public static void add(String[] args) {
    // initializing a new integer array of size args.length
    // Well every new int array has its values on 0, so sum over all 0 is 0
    // that's not really surprising
    int[] add = new int[args.length];

    // something is missing in here!
    for (int j = 0; j < args.length; j++) {
        add[j] = Integer.parseInt(args[j]);
    }
    // missing end

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < add.length; i++) {
        sum += add[i];
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

So if nothing else is wrong. This should do it.

Comment: I recommend using `j = 1` instead of `j = 0` or `-add` will cause a NumberFormatException.

Comment: @Tom can you provide your reasoning?

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the help, this is my first time using parse. I suppose I should read up more on it.

Comment: @KickButtowski I already did. `-add` is the first entry in array `args` (I don't think that he filtered it). Therefore it will cause the mentioned Exception.

Comment: @Tom Not really, -add is the name of the method. So the args are numerized from 0 to n.

Comment: @sxleixer I didn't knew you can invoke private methods from the command line. Should be a new feature ... isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        add(args);
    }

    public static void add(String[] args) {
        int[] add = new int[args.length];

        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < add.length; i++) {
                // Add this line 
                add[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
                sum += add[i];
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}

or
class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        add(args);
    }

    public static void add(String[] args) {

        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                sum += Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why even have the `add` array?  Or for that matter, an `add` method?

Comment: In there for clarity I think :-)

Comment: Its unnecessary code that is confusing.  Note that the OP is working on homework. Turning this in (not that we *should* be encouraging people to copy homework from SO) would have several points taken off for some unnecessary and ugly code. One should write as clean (and this isn't) code as possible when describing how to fix the problem so that the OP can learn how to write better code. Repeating mistakes doesn't help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting to add anything to the integer array; you're merely initializing it and stating its length.

```
private static void add(String[] args)
    String[] add = args;//actually set it equal to the args array, so it has all of the same values.
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < add.length; i++){
        sum += Integer.parseInt(add[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

or even simpler:

```
private static void add(String[] args)
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < args.length; i++){
        sum += Integer.parseInt(args[i]);//simply use the passed array.
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```